# Read file and display its contents in Go

Tags: go

I'm new to Go, I want to do a simple program that reads filename from user and display it's contents back to user. This is what I have so far:

```
fname := "D:\myfolder\file.txt"

f, err := os.Open(fname)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

var buff []byte
defer f.Close()
buff = make([]byte, 1024)
for {
    n, err := f.Read(buff)

    if n > 0 {
        fmt.Println(string(buff[:n]))
    }
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
}
```

but I get error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Presumably if you cd to myfolder and change the path to file.txt it works?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the backslashes in `fname` is the reason. Try with double backslash (`\\`).

Answer (score 2):

Put the filename in backquotes. This makes it a raw string literal. With raw string literals, no escape sequences such as `\f` will be processed.

```
fname := `D:\myfolder\file.txt`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the unix '/' path separators instead.
Does the job.

```
fname := "D:/myfolder/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on learning Go! Though the question was about a specific error in the example, let's break it down line by line and learn a bit about some of the other issues that may be encountered:

```golang
fname := "D:\myfolder\file.txt"
```

Like C and many other languages, Go uses the backslash character for an "escape sequence". That is, certain characters that start with a backslash get translated into other characters that would be hard to see otherwise (eg. `\t` becomes a tab character, which may otherwise be indistinguishable from a space).

The fix is to use a raw string literal (use backticks instead of quotes) where no escape sequences are processed:

```golang
fname := `D:\myfolder\file.txt`
```

This fixes the initial error you were seeing by removing the invalid `\m` and `\f` escape sequences. A full list of escape sequences and more explanation can be found by reading the [String Literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) section of the Go spec.

```golang
f, err := os.Open(fname)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The first line of this chunk is good, but it can be improved. If an error occurs, there is no reason for our program to continue executing since we couldn't even open the file, so we should both print it (probably to standard error) and exit, preferably with a non-zero exit status to indicate that something bad happened. Also, as a matter of good habit we probably want to close the file at the end of the function if opening it was successful. Putting it right below the Open call is conventional and makes it easier when someone else is reading your code. I would rewrite this as:

```golang
f, err := os.Open(fname)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    os.Exit(2)
    // It is also common to replace these two lines with a call to log.Fatal
}
defer f.Close()
```

The last chunk is a bit complicated, and we could rewrite it in multiple ways. Right now it looks like this:

```golang
var buff []byte
defer f.Close()
buff = make([]byte, 1024)
for {
    n, err := f.Read(buff)

    if n > 0 {
        fmt.Println(string(buff[:n]))
    }
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
}
```

But we don't need to define our own buffering, because the standard library provides us with the [`bufio`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/) and [`bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) packages which can do this for us. In this case though, we probably don't need them because we can also replace the iteration with a call to [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) which does its own internal buffering. We could also use one of the other copy variants such as [`io.CopyBuffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyBuffer) if we wanted to use our own buffer. It's also missing some error handling, so we'll add that. Now this entire chunk becomes:

```golang
_, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error reading from file: `%s'\n", err)
    os.Exit(2)
}
// We're done!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation , that solved my issue  but when I accept path from user it makes the same error , func main(){
 fmt.Println("Enter path : ")
 dirpath := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
 actualpath, _ := dirpath.ReadString('\n')
 fmt.Println("Entered path ",actualpath) actualpath = strings.TrimRight(actualpath,"\r\n")
 s:= []string{"`",strings.TrimSpace(actualpath),"`"}
 newpath := strings.Join(s,"") 
 fmt.Println(strings.Compare(`D:\LMNTRIX\maillink.txt`,newpath))
 fmt.Println(newpath) 
 comapre returns -1 even after entering same path after clearing \r\n

Comment: That should work fine (and works fine for me on a Unix-like system). I'd print the exact bytes (eg using a format string like `fmt.Fprintf("% x", newpath)`) and see where they differ. Then maybe you can figure out what's going on.